# Dilogarithm integral $\int^x_0 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-t)\log(1-t)}{t}\, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

I am hoping to find a closed form for the following

$$\tag{1} \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k}{k^3} x^k $$

Using the generating function

$$\sum_{k\geq 1}H^{(n)}_k x^k = \frac{\operatorname{Li}_n(x)}{1-x}$$

I could find [this](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic136-40.html#p1065) by simple integration

So I am stuck at evaluating

$$\tag{2}\int^x_0 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-t)\log(1-t)}{t}\, dt$$

For $x=\pm 1$ the problem can be solved , but what about the general case ?

Comment: You mean $ \operatorname{Li}_2(1-t)= \mathrm{dilog}(1-t)$?

Comment: Well, I don't understand what is that notation but 

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(1-t) = -\int^{1-t}_0 \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\, dx$$

Comment: See what I added. The answer is correct.

Comment: Zaid, you noted that the integral is doable for $x=1$.  Perhaps you can demonstrate that the integral evaluates to $-\pi^4/120$ there. If not, I will.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: As I said the dilog is a special case of the polylog and that gives $\mathrm{dilog(z)}=\mathrm{Li}_2(z)$. So, computer algebra systems adopt different convention. I hope you have read the link I provided.

Comment: @RonGordon: Do not rush to judge things. I think I told you this before.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Oh, you did.  And I do not criticize your work lightly.  Unlike you, I actually carry out operations by hand and check with a second source like Mathematica before I make a judgment.  There is no doubt in my mind that the integral posted by the OP takes the value $-\pi^4/120$ at $x=1$.  The value in your graph, on the other hand, is $-\pi^4/72$ at $x=1$, again allowing for your elastic definition of a dilogarithm.  Your answer **does not agree** with the OP's integral at least at $x=1$, and I am sure everywhere else outside of $x=0$.  I am sorry to need to be blunt about it.

Comment: I have figured out, though, that $$\int_0^1 dt \frac{\text{Li}_2(t) \log{(1-t)}}{t} = -\frac{\pi^4}{72}$$  Maybe this explains your incorrect result.

Comment: @RonGordon: My evaluaton of the integral is based on the fact that $\mathrm{dilog(1-t)}=\mathrm{Li}_2(1-t)$ which is the origin convention that dilog is a special case of polylog $\mathrm{dilog(t)}=\mathrm{Li}_2(t)$ . Take your time to conciliate between the two conventions.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: how about allowing the OP to define what the various conventions mean?  His integral has no reference to any "dilog," which looks exactly the same as what's inside the integral anyway.  It is you that is confused, not I nor the OP.

Comment: @RonGordon , I proved the following 

$$\int^1_0 \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}\, \log(x)\,dx = \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k^2}-2\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k}{k^3}=\frac{-\pi^4}{120}$$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: This is equivalent to your integral at $x=1$.  That is the point I have been trying to make.  I hope you can now see your way through this miasma.

Comment: @RonGordon, don't worry I know what I am doing :)

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: Good that you got the point.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: I hope you have not got distracted by the downvote.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: By the way, I've looked at your problem on the other website. You are doing a nice work and my answer gives you the value of the integral. (+1) nice approach.

Comment: @mhennibenghorbal , thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of the integrand suggests the use of the reflection formula might come handy. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\limits_0^x Li_2(1-t) \frac{\log(1-t)}{t} dt =
\int\limits_0^x \left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \log(t) \log(1-t) - Li_2(t) \right) \cdot \frac{\log(1-t)}{t} dt \\
&&=-\frac{\pi^2}{6} Li_2(x) + \frac{1}{2} Li_2(x)^2 - \int\limits_0^x \log(t) \frac{\log(1-t)^2}{t} dt \\
&&=-\frac{\pi^2}{6} Li_2(x) + \frac{1}{2} Li_2(x)^2 - \left(-2 S_{2,2}(x) + 2 \log(x) S_{1,2}(x)\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $S_{p,q}(x)$ are the Nielsen generalized polylogarithms (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NielsenGeneralizedPolylogarithm.html   for definition).

Answer (score 8):

$$\begin{align}
&\int^x_0 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-t)\log(1-t)}{t}\,dt=\\
&\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(1-x)}2-2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(1-\frac1x\right)-2\operatorname{Li}_4(1-x)+2\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\frac1x\right)\log^2\left(\frac1x-1\right)+\\
&\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\left(\log^2\left(\frac1x-1\right)+\log(1-x)\log(x)\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\log\left(\frac1x\right)+\\&2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-\frac1x\right)\log\left(\frac1x-1\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\left(\log\left(\frac1x-1\right)+\log(x)\right)-\\
&\frac14\log^4\left(\frac1x\right)+\frac13\log^3(1-x)\left(2\log(x)-\log\left(\frac1x\right)\right)-\\
&\log(1-x)\left(\log^3\left(\frac1x\right)+\frac13\pi^2\log\left(\frac1x\right)+\frac{\pi^2}6\log(x)\right)+\\&\log^2(1-x)\left(-\log^2\left(\frac1x\right)+\frac12\log^2(x)+\log(x)\log\left(\frac1x\right)-\frac{\pi^2}6\right)-\frac{11\pi^4}{360},\end{align}$$
that can be checked by taking derivatives from both sides.

See the corresponding indefinite integral at [*WolframAlpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28PolyLog%5B2%2C+1-t%5DLog%5B1-t%5D%29%2Ft%2Ct%5D).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof for your sum not the integral,

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3482014) we have

$$\frac12\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx=\operatorname{Li}_4(y)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)+\ln y\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^2}y^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}
{n^3}y^n$$

[Substitute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^2}y^{n}=\operatorname{Li}_3(y)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)+\ln(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\frac12\ln y\ln^2(1-y)+\zeta(3)$$

[and](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3482240)

$$\frac12\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$$
$$=\frac14\ln^2y\ln^2(1-y)-\frac16\ln^3y\ln(1-y)+\frac1{24}\ln^4(1-y)+\frac16\ln^3\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\ln(1-y)\\-\frac12\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)+\ln \left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-\frac12\ln^2y\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\\+\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)-\operatorname{Li}_4(y)+\frac12\ln^2(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)-\ln (1-y)\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)+\operatorname{Li}_4(1-y)-\zeta(4)$$

we obtain that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}y^n$$
$$=\zeta(4)-\frac1{24}\ln^4(1-y)+\frac16\ln^3y\ln(1-y)-\frac16\ln^3\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\ln(1-y)+\frac14\ln^2y\ln^2(1-y)$$

$$-\frac12\ln^2(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\frac12\ln^2y\operatorname{Li}_2(y)+\ln (1-y)\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)$$

$$-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)+\ln y\ln(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\zeta(3)\ln y+2\operatorname{Li}_4(y)-\operatorname{Li}_4(1-y)$$

$$+\frac12\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-\ln \left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)$$

---

If we use Landen's identity

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(y)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)=-\frac12\ln^2(1-y)$$

and

$$\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)+\operatorname{Li}_3(y)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)=\zeta(3)+\frac16\ln^3(1-y)-\frac12\ln^2y\ln(1-y)+\zeta(2)\ln y$$

the sum simplifies to

> \begin{align}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}y^n&=\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_4(y)-\operatorname{Li}_4(1-y)-\ln(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_3(y)\\
> &\quad +\frac12\ln^2(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(y)+\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(y)+\frac16\ln^4(1-y)-\frac16\ln y\ln^3(1-y)\\
> &\quad+\frac12\zeta(2)\ln^2(1-y)+\zeta(3)\ln(1-y)+\zeta(4)
> \end{align}

---

To get your integral, integrate by parts

$$\int_0^y\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{x}dx=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}dx$$

$$=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(H_n^{(2)}-\frac1{n^2}\right)\int_0^y x^{n-1}\ln x\ dx$$

$$=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(H_n^{(2)}-\frac1{n^2}\right)\left(\ln y\frac{y^n}{n}-\frac{y^n}{n^2}\right)$$

$$=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)+\operatorname{Li}_4(y)+\ln y\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}y^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}y^n$$

by Cauchy product we have

$$\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(y)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}y^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}y^n-3\operatorname{Li}_4(y)$$

which gives

$$\int_0^y\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{x}dx$$
$$=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(y)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)-2\operatorname{Li}_4(y)+\ln y\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}y^n+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}y^n$$

[where](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}^{(2)}}{n}y^{n}=\operatorname{Li}_3(y)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)-\ln(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)-\zeta(2)\ln(1-y)-2\zeta(3)$$

Answer (score 1):

$0<x<1$, 
\begin{align}
J(x)&=\int^x_0 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-t)\log(1-t)}{t}\, dt\\
\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)&=-\int_0^{1-x}\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}dt\\
&{\overset{y=1-t}=}-\int_x^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=\Big[\ln(1-t)\ln t\Big]_x^1-\int_x^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}dt\\
&=-\ln(1-x)\ln x+\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\\
\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt&=-\Big[\ln(1-t)\ln t\Big]_0^x+\int_0^x \frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}dt\\
&=-\ln(1-x)\ln x-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\\
J(x)&=-\Big[\operatorname{Li}_2(1-t)\operatorname{Li}_2(t)\Big]_0^x+\int_0^x \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(t)\ln t}{1-t}dt\\
&=-\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\int_0^x \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(t)\ln t}{1-t}dt\\
&=\ln(1-x)\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\zeta(2)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)+\int_0^x \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(t)\ln t}{1-t}\,dt\\
\int_0^x \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(t)\ln t}{1-t}\,dt&=\left[\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln u}{1-u}\,du\right)\operatorname{Li}_2(t)\right]_0^x+\int_0^x \left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln u}{1-u}\,du\right)\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}\,dt\\
&=-\ln(1-x)\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)-\int_0^x \frac{\Big(\ln(1-t)\ln t+\operatorname{Li}_2(t)\Big)\ln(1-t)}{t}dt\\
&=-\ln(1-x)\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)-\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2(1-t)\ln t}{t}dt\\
J(x)&=\frac{\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)}{2}-\zeta(2)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2(1-t)\ln t}{t}dt\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)}{2}-\zeta(2)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\Big[\frac{\ln^2(1-t)\ln^2 t}{2}\Big]_0^x -\int_0^x \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)}{2}-\zeta(2)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2 x}{2}-\int_0^x \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt\\
K(x)&=-\int_0^x \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^x \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \text{H}_n t^n\right)\ln^2 t dt\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \text{H}_n \left(\int_0^x t^n\ln^2 t \,dt\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\text{H}_{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \left(\int_0^x t^n\ln^2 t dt\right)\\
&=\left(\ln^2 x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{n+1}-2\ln x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}\right)-\\
&\left(\ln^2 x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}-2\ln x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^4}\right)\\
&=\ln^2 x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n}x^{n}}{n}-2\ln x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n}x^{n}}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n}x^{n}}{n^3}-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ln^2 x+\\
&2\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\ln x-2\operatorname{Li}_4(x)\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n}x^{n}}{n}&=\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1-x)\\
K(x)&=-2\ln x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n}x^{n}}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n}x^{n}}{n^3}+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2 x+\\
&2\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\ln x-2\operatorname{Li}_4(x)\\
\end{align}
$\boxed{\displaystyle J(x)=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)-\zeta(2)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\ln x-2\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-2\ln x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n}x^{n}}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{H}_{n}x^{n}}{n^3}}$

Answer (score 0):

Start with using the reflection formula of the dilogarithm function,

$$\text{Li}_2(1-x)=\zeta(2)-\ln(x)\ln(1-x)-\text{Li}_2(x)$$

$$\Longrightarrow I=\zeta(2)\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{-\zeta(2)}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{\text{Beta function:}\ -\frac12\zeta(4)}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\text{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx}_{-\frac12\text{Li}_2^2(x)|_0^1=-\frac54\zeta(4)}=-\frac34\zeta(4)$$