# Infinite Series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^5 2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, zeta-functions

Given the *n*th harmonic number $ H_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{j}$, we get from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246136/on-generalizing-the-harmonic-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnkzn-s-k-1) that apparently,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^k}z^n= S_{k-1,2}(z) + \rm{Li}_{\,k+1}(z)$$

for $-1\leq z\leq 1$, and with *Nielsen generalized polylogarithm* $S_{n,p}(z)$ and polylogarithm $\rm{Li}_n(z)$. Hence for small $k$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2\, 2^n}= S_{1,2}\big(\tfrac12\big)+\rm{Li}_3\big(\tfrac12\big)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^3\, 2^n}= S_{2,2}\big(\tfrac12\big)+\rm{Li}_4\big(\tfrac12\big)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^4\, 2^n}= S_{3,2}\big(\tfrac12\big)+\rm{Li}_5\big(\tfrac12\big)$$

and so on. Explicitly, given $a=\ln 2$,

$$S_{1,2}\big(\tfrac12\big) +\tfrac1{6}a^3-\tfrac18 \zeta(3)=0 $$

$$S_{2,2}\big(\tfrac12\big) +\tfrac1{168}a^4+\tfrac17a^2\,\rm{Li}_2\big(\tfrac12\big)+\tfrac17a\,\rm{Li}_3\big(\tfrac12\big)-\tfrac18\zeta(4) = 0$$

which are discussed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604316/infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn22n) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909228/infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn32n) post. And by yours truly,

$$S_{3,2}\big(\tfrac12\big) -A+B  = 0$$

$$A = \tfrac{41}{840}a^5+\tfrac5{21}a^3\,\rm{Li}_2\big(\tfrac12\big)+\tfrac47a^2\,\rm{Li}_3\big(\tfrac12\big)+a\,\rm{Li}_4\big(\tfrac12\big) + \rm{Li}_5\big(\tfrac12\big) $$

$$B=\tfrac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\tfrac18a\,\zeta(4)-\tfrac1{32}\zeta(5)$$

> **Q:** What, however, is the explicit evaluation in ordinary polylogs of the next steps, namely $S_{4,2}\big(\tfrac12\big)$ and $S_{5,2}\big(\tfrac12\big)$?

**P.S.** Try as I might, they resist being evaluated and [there are indications](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/974564/4781) these higher order integrals may not be expressible by ordinary polylogs.

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944065/find-the-closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2nn4

Comment: @nospoon: Ah, that's the case $k=4$. Didn't see that.

Comment: @nospoon: If there is a recursion involved (as the answer in your link seems to suggest), then it may be possible to find all subsequent steps.

Comment: Another relevant link for $k=5$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972775/what-is-a-closed-form-for-large-int-01-frac-ln31x-ln2xxdx

Comment: @nospoon: Thanks for the link. At first, I thought a closed-form for $k=5$ was found, but it just expresses it in several Nielsen polylogarithms. Kindly see this [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249300/relating-int-01-frac-ln-xn-1-ln1xpxdx-and-int-01-frac-ln).

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\Li}{\mathrm{Li}}$You are *probably* correct that the sufficiently higher order sums do not have a closed form in terms of classical polylogarithms.  In particular the $k=6$ sum should not have such an expression, although this claim rests on some big conjectures (the so-called Grothendeick Period Conjecture, or some sufficiently special-case).  However the $k=5$ case does appear to have a closed form, as given below.

Essentially there is an algebraically defined version of (Nielsen) polylogs, the so-called motivic (Nielsen) polylogs.  These objects have a much richer structure, and there is an invariant (the coproduct $\Delta$ and the cobracket $\delta$) which can distinguish Nielsen from classical polylogs.  The cobracket $\delta\Li_n(x) = 0 $, whereas $ \delta S_{5,2}(x) = \Li_2(x) \wedge \Li_5(1) + \Li_4(x) \wedge \Li_3(1) \neq 0 $; the factors of the wedge are viewed modulo products.  In particular, $ \delta S_{5,2}(\frac{1}{2}) = \Li_4(\frac{1}{2}) \wedge \zeta(3) \neq 0 $.  (Can check that $L_4(\frac{1}{2}) / \zeta(4) \not\in \mathbb{Q} $, where $ L_4 $ is some single-valued version of $\Li_4$.)

However $ \delta S_{4,2}(x) = \Li_3(x) \wedge \Li_3(1) $, and since $ \Li_3(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{7}{8} \zeta(3) - \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) \log(2) + \frac{1}{6} \log(2)^3 $, one gets
$$
  \delta S_{4,2}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big) = \frac{7}{8} \zeta(3) \wedge \zeta(3) = 0 \,,
$$
by the antisymmetry of the wedge.  Another Big Conjecture from Goncharov claims that classical polylogs are exactly the kernel of this cobracket, so conjecturally we *should* be able to expression $ S_{4,2}(\frac{1}{2}) $ in terms of $ \Li_6 $.

In the [answer I posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3386981/112256) to another of your questions, I gave an explicit formula for $S_{4,2}(-1)$ and some explanation via the coproduct of how one obtains it (up to a rational numerically determined coefficient of $\zeta(6)$).  One can also get a formula for $S_{4,2}(\frac{1}{2})$, and hence for sum for $k=5$, from the $S_{4,2}(-1)$ reduction.  In particular
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^5} = {} &  S_{4,2}(-1) - \frac{31}{32} \zeta(6) = \zeta(\overline{5}, 1) - \frac{31}{32} \zeta(6) \\
\overset{?}{=} {} & \frac{1}{13} \bigg(\frac{1}{3}\Li_6\Big(-\frac{1}{8}\Big)-162
 \Li_6\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\Big)-126
 \Li_6\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)\bigg)
 -\frac{4783 }{1248}\zeta (6)
 +\frac{3}{8} \zeta (3)^2
 \\ &
 {}+\frac{31}{16} \zeta (5) \log(2)
 -\frac{15}{26} \zeta (4) \log ^2(2)
 +\frac{3}{104} \zeta (2) \log^4(2)
 -\frac{1}{208} \log ^6(2) \,, \\[2em]
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^5 2^n} \overset{?}{=} {} & -\frac{1}{26} \left(
\frac{1}{3}\Li_6\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)
-162\Li_6\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)
-204\Li_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)
-\frac{101 }{624} \zeta (6)
-\frac{7}{16} \zeta (3)^2 \\
&+\Big(\Li_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
-\zeta (5)+\frac{1}{2}\zeta (2) \zeta (3) \Big) \log (2)
+\frac{73}{208} \zeta (4) \log ^2(2)\\
&-\frac{1}{6} \zeta (3) \log^3(2)
+\frac{17}{624} \zeta (2) \log ^4(2)
-\frac{11}{6240}\log ^6(2) \,.
\end{align*}
Amusingly, since $ \Li_3(\phi^{-2}) = \frac{4}{5} \zeta(3) + \text{products} $, where $ \phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} $ is the golden ratio, we can also conjecturally evaluate $S_{4,2}(\phi^{-2})$ (up to a rational but numerically determined coefficient of $\zeta(6)$).  We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^5 \phi^{2n}} \overset{?}{=} {} &
\frac{1}{396} \Big( 
2 \Li_6\big( \phi ^{-6} \big)
 -128 \Li_6\big( \phi ^{-3}\big)
+1197\Li_6\big(\phi ^{-2}\big)
-576 \Li_6\big(\phi^{-1} \big)
 \Big) \\
&+\frac{35 }{99}\zeta (6)
+\frac{2}{5}  \zeta (3)^2
+ \Li_5 \left(\phi ^{-2}\right) \log (\phi)
-\zeta (5)\log (\phi )
\\ &
+\frac{2}{11} \zeta (4) \log ^2(\phi )
-\zeta (3) \Li_3\left(\phi ^{-2}\right)
+\frac{10}{33} \zeta (2) \log ^4(\phi )
-\frac{79}{990} \log ^6(\phi ) \,.
\end{align*}
The only uncertainty in these formulae should be the (necessarily rational) coefficient of $\zeta(6)$, all other terms are fixed by analysis of the coproduct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ denotes $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)\ln x}{x}\ dx$

I proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3249294)

> \begin{align}
> I&=-120\operatorname{Li}_6\left(\frac12\right)-72\ln2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-24\ln^22\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+78\zeta(6)+\frac34\ln2\zeta(5)\\
> &\quad-\frac32\ln^22\zeta(4)-3\ln^32\zeta(3)+2\ln^42\zeta(2)+12\zeta^2(3)-12\ln2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\
> &\quad-\frac{17}{30}\ln^62+24\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^52^n}\tag{1}
> \end{align}

On the other hand and by applying integration by parts we have

\begin{align}
I=-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)\ln^2x}{1+x}\ dx
\end{align}
You can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3254834) the following identity

$$-\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\left(H_n^3-3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)$$

Replacing $x$ with $-x$ yields

$$-\frac{\ln^3(1+x)}{1+x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n\left(H_n^3-3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)$$

Now we can write
\begin{align}
I&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(H_n^3-3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)\int_0^1 x^n \ln^2x\ dx\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(H_{n-1}^3-3H_{n-1}H_{n-1}^{(2)}+2H_{n-1}^{(3)}\right)\int_0^1 x^{n-1} \ln^2x\ dx\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(H_{n}^3-3H_{n}H_{n}^{(2)}+2H_{n}^{(3)}+\frac{6H_n}{n^3}-\frac{3H_n^2}{n}+\frac{3H_n^{(2)}}{n}-\frac{6}{n^2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{n^3}\right)\\
\end{align}

Then

> \begin{align}
> I&=12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^3}-4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^3}{n^3}-8\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(3)}}{n^3}-24\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^5}\\
> &\quad+12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^2}{n^4}-12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(2)}}{n^4}+24\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^6}\tag{2}
> \end{align}

---

We can see from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that our target sum is related to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^5}$.

I am not sure if the alternating sums in $(2)$ have closed form or not but I am sure that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^5}$ has no closed form because the power of the denominator is odd more than 3. So the target sum has no closed form unless $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^5}$ cancels out with other sums somehow which I doubt.