# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^2(x)\ln(1+x)\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^2(x)\ln(1+x)\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$$

$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+\cdots\right)\left[\ln(x)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^2 \mathrm dx$$

This integral takes the form of $$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^n\left[\ln(x)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^2 \mathrm dx, n\ge0$$

$$u=\left[\ln(x)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^2$$

$$u^{'}=\frac{2\ln(x)\ln(1+1/x)\left[(1+x)\ln(1+1/x)-\ln(x)\right]}{x(1+x)}$$

$$v=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

$$J=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\left[\ln(x)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^2-\frac{2}{n+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}\cdot\frac{\ln(x)\ln(1+1/x)\left[(1+x)\ln(1+1/x)-\ln(x)\right]}{x(1+x)}\mathrm dx$$

Wow... this is getting too tough I am totally lose, any help.

Comment: Firstly this expansion of $\ln{(1+x)}$ is only valid for $-1\lt x\le1$ which does not cover the given integral bounds. Then the integrand of $J$ does not converge to zero for $n\ge2$ so this approach does not seem like it would work anyway.

Comment: Mathematica gives $$I=6(\zeta(3))^2+\frac{\pi^6}{60}\approx24.69279801\dots$$

Comment: pheeew, I am glad there is a closed form!

Comment: The [generalization of this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3285805) is likewise solvable using the same approach as Felix Marin's answer and from my answer here we get some identities for Nielsen polylogarithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{I \equiv
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^{2}\pars{x}
> \ln\pars{1 + x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 + {1 \over x}}
> \,{\dd x \over x} =
> {\pi^{6} \over 60} + 6\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}:\ {\LARGE ?}}$.

\begin{align}
I & \equiv
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^{2}\pars{x}
\ln\pars{1 + x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 + {1 \over x}}
\,{\dd x \over x}}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^{2}\pars{x}
\ln\pars{1 + x}
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 + x} - \ln\pars{x}}^{\, 2}
\,{\dd x \over x}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln^{2}\pars{x - 1}
\ln\pars{x}
\bracks{\ln\pars{x} - \ln\pars{x - 1}}^{\, 2}
\,{\dd x \over x - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{1}^{0}\ln^{2}\pars{{1 \over x} - 1}
\ln\pars{1 \over x}
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 \over x} -
\ln\pars{{1 \over x} - 1}}^{\, 2}\
\,{-\dd x/x^{2} \over 1/x - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{1}
{\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - x} - \ln\pars{x}}^{\, 2}
\ln\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x
\\[8mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln\pars{x}\ln^{4}\pars{1 - x} \over x\pars{1 - x}}
\,\dd x +
2\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln^{3}\pars{1 - x} \over x\pars{1 - x}}
\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & -
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over
x\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x
\\[8mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln\pars{x}\ln^{4}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x -\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{4}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & +
2\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln^{3}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x +
2\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{3}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & -
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over
x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln^{3}\pars{1 - x} \over
x}\,\dd x
\\[8mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{4}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{3}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] & +
\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln^{3}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x -\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln\pars{x}\ln^{4}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> The above integrals are related to derivatives, respect $\ds{\mu}$ and $\ds{\nu}$ with
>   $\ds{\pars{\mu,\nu} \to \pars{0^{+},0}}$, of

\begin{align}
\mc{I}\pars{\mu,\nu} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu}\bracks{\pars{1 - x}^{\nu} - 1} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu - 1}\pars{1 - x}^{\nu}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu - 1}\,\dd x =
{\Gamma\pars{\mu}\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu + 1}} - {1 \over \mu}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \mu}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu + 1}} - 1}
\end{align}
as
$$
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{m}\pars{x}\ln^{n}\pars{1 - x} \over x} \, \dd x =
\lim_{{\large\mu \to 0^{+}} \atop {\large\nu \to 0}}{\partial^{m + n}\mc{I}\pars{\mu,\nu} \over \partial\mu^{m}\,\partial\nu^{n}}
$$

---

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{-\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{4}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} & \ds{\phantom{-}{8\pi^{6} \over 315}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{3}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} & \ds{-\,{\pi^{6} \over 105} + 6\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln^{3}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} & \ds{-\,{23\pi^{6} \over 1260} + 12\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{-\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln\pars{x}\ln^{4}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} & \ds{\phantom{-}{2\pi^{6} \over 105} - 12\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

> Note that

$\ds{{8\pi^{6} \over 315} +
\bracks{-\,{\pi^{6} \over 105} + 6\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}} +
\bracks{-\,{23\pi^{6} \over 1260} + 12\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}} +
\bracks{{2\pi^{6} \over 105} - 12\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}} =
\bbx{{\pi^{6} \over 60} + 6\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}}}$

which is the *final answer*.

Comment: Nice, I was wondering how to get the bounds to $(0,1)$ and rewrite the integrand with $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(1-x)$, but just couldn't do it :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Whenever we see a $\displaystyle 1 + x$ factor, we swithch to $\displaystyle 1 + x \mapsto x$. Later on, $\displaystyle x \mapsto 1/x$ yields intervals $\displaystyle\left(0,1\right)$ with factors $\displaystyle 1 - x$ everywhere. Thanks.

Comment: You may also be interested in [the generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3285805). Currently working out if this gives us some values of the Nielsen polylogarithm.

Comment: Is there any way to get WA to evaluate $\mathcal I$? I'm trying to take the limit of 8th order partial derivatives, and the best I could do is get WA to tell me [the derivatives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E8%2Fdx%5E2dy%5E6+Beta%5Bx,+y%5D+where+y%3D1), but not the limit.

Comment: Maybe the change of variable $y=\dfrac{x}{1+x}$ ($x=\dfrac{y}{1-y},dx=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}dy$) makes the things a little simpler

Comment: @FDP I'll study your idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the Taylor expansions of $\ln$ do not converge on the entirety of $(0,\infty)$. Instead, let $x\mapsto1/x$ on $(1,\infty)$ to get two integrals on $(0,1)$:

$$I_1=\int_0^1\ln^2(x)\ln(1+x)\ln^2\left(1+\frac1x\right)~\frac{\mathrm dx}x$$

$$I_2=\int_0^1\ln^2(x)\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)\ln^2(1+x)~\frac{\mathrm dx}x$$

Since $\ln(1+1/x)=\ln(1+x)-\ln(x)$ we can multiply them out as follows:

$$I_1=\int_0^1\ln^2(x)\ln^3(1+x)-2\ln^3(x)\ln^2(1+x)+\ln^4(x)\ln(1+x)~\frac{\mathrm dx}x$$

$$I_2=\int_0^1\ln^2(x)\ln^3(1+x)-\ln^3(x)\ln^2(1+x)~\frac{\mathrm dx}x$$

$$I=I_1+I_2=\int_0^12\ln^2(x)\ln^3(1+x)-3\ln^3(x)\ln^2(1+x)+\ln^4(x)\ln(1+x)~\frac{\mathrm dx}x$$

[None of these parts have known solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3249646/272831), so either I made a mistake, this is the wrong approach, or it is possible to continue with this specific combination of coefficients, or perhaps Mathematica's closed form is wrong, though I wouldn't know.

Comment: The third one is pretty easy using the power expansion of $\ln(1+x)$. $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 x\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=\frac{93}{4}\zeta(6)$$ 
The first one is also known around here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/972775/515527. But there's some simplification going on between the first and the second integral. I guess one might prefer to evaluate them togheter.

Comment: Oop well yes the third one is fairly obvious, but the other two... D:

Comment: Your approach is correct, and Mathematica's closed-form is also correct. Expressed as Nielsen polylogs, your answer is,
$$I = -24S_{3,3}(-1)+36S_{4,2}(-1)-24S_{5,1}(-1)$$
with the third one as,
$$I = -24S_{3,3}(-1)+36S_{4,2}(-1)+93/4\,\zeta(6)$$
Since
$$I = 6\zeta^2(3)+\pi^6/60$$
This implies
$$-24S_{3,3}(-1)+36S_{4,2}(-1) =6\zeta^3(3)-\pi^6/126$$
but neither of those two Nielsen polylogs (separately) have a known closed-form.

Comment: Each of these parts have known solution. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.12113).