# Is there a closed form without MZV for $ \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_k}{k^6\:2^k}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

While evaluating the weight $7$ integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(1-x\right)\ln^3\left(1+x\right)}{1+x}\:dx$

I managed to prove that

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(1-x\right)\ln^3\left(1+x\right)}{1+x}\:dx=\frac{3465}{32}\zeta \left(7\right)-\frac{423}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(6\right)-\frac{81}{2}\zeta \left(3\right)\zeta \left(4\right)-36\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_k}{k^6\:2^k}$$
$$+72\operatorname{Li}_7\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+36\ln \left(2\right)\operatorname{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-54\zeta \left(2\right)\zeta \left(5\right)-36\ln ^2\left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)\zeta \left(3\right)+90\ln ^2\left(2\right)\zeta \left(5\right)$$
$$-21\ln ^3\left(2\right)\zeta \left(4\right)+\frac{21}{2}\ln ^4\left(2\right)\zeta \left(3\right)+36\ln \left(2\right)\zeta ^2\left(3\right)-\frac{21}{10}\ln ^5\left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{5}{28}\ln ^7\left(2\right)$$
While using the Mathemathica package written by Pisco found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243/a-remarkable-logarithmic-integral-int-01-frac-log2-1-x-log2-x-log31?noredirect=1&lq=1) to calculate that integral I saw that the result had MZV which is an indicator that the sum might not have a nice closed form but im quite stubborn and i'd like to know if this sum can be computed without these.

Comment: I am hopeful that, much like the rest of the terms, it may be something of the form $\frac{n_1}{n_2}\ln^{n_3}(2)\zeta(n_5)\zeta(n_6)$ where $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. If true, perhaps there is gap of sorts in a pattern of the other terms that could be neatly filled in by such.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3247329

Comment: The answer by Steven Charlton in the question linked by @nospoon is very informative. Steven proved, via [some advanced theories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.04770.pdf), that $\sum H_n/(n^52^n)$ can be expressed using $\text{Li}_6(1/4), \text{Li}_6(1/8)$. On the other hand, the same theory predicts non-existence of closed form for $\sum H_n/(n^62^n)$ (in terms of ordinary polylog). So the answer of your question is pessimistic, your sum almost surely involves MZV.